# Passing a C++ package library to a doParallel cluster

Tags: r, plyr

I have a some plyr code that is meant to run a Rcpp function that I have written:

```
nodes = detectCores()
cl = makeCluster(nodes)
registerDoParallel(cl)

l = llply(mylist, function(x) {
 .Call("myfancyfunction", PACKAGE = "mypackage", ...)
}, .parallel = TRUE, .paropts = list(.packages = "mypackage"))
```

However, even when I include the package I get the error:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : 
  task 1 failed - ""myfancyfunction" not available for .Call() for package "mypackage""
```

How do I make my libraries accessible to the parallel processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error doesn't indicate any issue with plyr or parallel processing; it means you haven't properly registered your C/C++ routine in your package. For example, this works:

```
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)
nodes = detectCores()
cl = makeCluster(nodes)
registerDoParallel(cl)
l <- llply(list(1,2), function(x) {
  .Call("endpoints", 1L, 1L, 1L, TRUE, PACKAGE="xts")
}, .parallel=TRUE, .paropts=list(.packages="xts"))
```

`library(mypackage); .Call("myfancyfunction", x, PACKAGE="mypackage")` in a normal R session likely throws the same error.

See [Registering native routines](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Registering-native-routines) in *Writing R Extensions* for details on ways you can register `myfancyfunction`.

Comment: I had been forgetting to include `useDynLib(mypackage)` in NAMESPACE, so the C++ files were not getting loaded.